# How to set read only false in select box and When a checkbox is selected it would be editable. In my jquery code disable is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

How to make select box  is disabled  and When a check box is selected it would be editable. In my java script code disable is not working.

```
<td>
    <select name="ShiftType" id="ShiftType" disabled="true">
            <option value="Morning">Morning</option>
            <option value="AfterNoon">After Noon</option>
            <option value="FullDay">Full Day</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

**jQuery**

```
if ($("#" + id).is(':checked')) 
{ 
    $("#ShiftType").attr('disable', false); 
}
```

Comment: $("#selectboxId").attr('disable', false);

Comment: 'In my java script code disable is not working.' in which javascript code. please give here.

Comment: In your code Change `disable` to `disabled`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#checkbox").click(function() {
   if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $("#dropdown").prop("disabled", true);
   } else {
      $("#dropdown").prop("disabled", false);  
   }
 });
});
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/3opdcf8c/1/**

Comment: in my code disabled function is not working  $("#dropdown").prop("disabled", true);

Comment: Check my answer with Demo which help to you

Comment: In select box read only will not work. so i had used disabled= true, Then i want to change it to disabled= false using jquery or java script.i had used    document.getElementById("selectboxId").readOnly = false; and   $("#selectboxId").prop("disabled", true); this is not working in my code

Comment: <td><select name="ShiftType" id="ShiftType" disabled="true"> 
                                            <option value="Morning">Morning</option>
                                            <option value="AfterNoon">After Noon</option>
                                            <option value="FullDay">Full Day</option>
                                        </select></td>



in jquery 
  if ($("#" + id).is(':checked')) {
 $("#ShiftType").attr('disable', false);
}

Comment: In question you can edit with your code here I cant find what you do?

Comment: $("#ShiftType").attr('disable', false); this diabled function is not working in my code

Comment: Do not forgot to accept/upvote when answer is helpful.